# $scope object get updated too when updating local var variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have $scope.stock_filters object and i want to assign to a new variable something like this.

```
var new_data_object = $scope.stock_filters[$scope.key_filter];
```

Now when i update a key of this object like

```
new_data_object.name = 'blablabla';
```

Why does **$scope.stock_filters[$scope.key_filter].name** get updated too ?

What am I doing wrong ? How I can fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the instance by reference, which is why both references are being affected.  If you just want to create a copy of an instance, you can use angular.copy:

```
 var new_data_object = angular.copy($scope.stock_filters[$scope.key_filter]);

 new_data_object.name = 'blablabla';
```

Comment: Thank You very much , i wonder why i never encounter this simple problem before -*-